# JavaScript - Clicking on an image on a website

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript how can I click on an image on a website.

EDIT:
This is the code of the image.

```
<div class="comment_gravatarn">
<a target="_parent" href="http://www.example.com">
<img src="image.160x160.jpg" alt="Example Text" title="Example Text" width="160" sf_validated="1">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have an image that when clicked will take you another, either internal or external, source? Or something different?

Comment: I can click on any image, on any website, without writing any code.

Comment: `src`, `alt` and `title` are attributes, not tags (well, `<title>` is a tag). But how are they related to clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("img[ATTR='value']").click();
});
```

That's a generic form, where you would change `ATTR` for the attribute you wanted to search, and replace `value` with the known value. Eg:

Given the following img tag:

```
<img src="myImage.png" alt="AltAttr" title="MyTitle" />
```

I would probably select it by `src` :

```
$(function() {
    $("img[src='myImage.png']").click();
});
```

by `alt` :

```
$(function() {
    $("img[alt='AltAttr']").click();
});
```

by title :

```
$(function() {
    $("img[title='MyTitle']").click();
});
```

I recommend looking up css selectors, as that's what jQuery and `document.querySelector()` use.

**LINK:** [W3C Article on Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: You really don't need to use jQuery for something as simple as this. It's not going to help [performance](http://jsperf.com/jquery-click-event-vs-pure-javascript/2), either.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, I wouldn't use jQuery for just this task. Given the content of the question (or lack thereof), I went with the method that I thought syntactically would be easiest for him to follow.  Great link, though!

Answer (score 0):

> Using JavaScript how can I click on an image

You can click on any image without javascript, using your mouse.

But if you need to simulate a click using javascript, you can use [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click):

```
myImage.click(); // myImage is a reference to the desired image
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple: just use [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) on the image to simulate a click.

You'd have to select the image somehow, using `document.getElementById()` or `document.getElementsByTagName()`, for example.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].click();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/qR4QD/)

Comment: Would this be the correct syntax for using getElementsByClassName ?document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0].click();

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery here. Using that you can select image. So the code will be like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var src = "/*Src for your image*/";

    $("img[src='"+src+"']").click(function(){

        //Your code here
    });
});
```

You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RUE4t/)

But I strongly recomend to use its parent's id or class so that you can select it using :

```
$("#parent_id > img").click();
```

And also dont forget to install jquery before doing any of these.

Comment: You *really* don't need to use jQuery for something as simple as this. It's not going to help [performance](http://jsperf.com/jquery-click-event-vs-pure-javascript/2), either.